# What does "PI" mean in Australia?

Tags: funding, terminology, australia

In the United States a "PI" is a principal investigator.  This is someone who leads grant applications.  What does "PI" mean in Australia?

Comment: Inspired by this question:  https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/108352/13240

Comment: It's not 3.14159265?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni no, snake and sydney, sorry Steak and Kidney pie..

Answer (score 7):

In Australia, "PI" means partner investigator.  This is someone who is involved in a grant application but is **not** eligible for funding.  For example, they might be an international collaborator.

A grant applicant is a "Chief Investigator" or "CI."

Reference:  http://www.arc.gov.au/eligibility-matters